# Return data from http request

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm building a little framework with Node.js, and I would try to use data from an API but I don't know why it doesn't work (asynchronous but ??).

```
var request = require('request');

var IndexController = function(request, parameters) {
    this.request = request;
    this.parameters = parameters;
}

IndexController.prototype.execute = function () {
    var url = "https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.1/champion?api_key=#my-private-key";
    var data;

    request(url, function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            data = JSON.parse(body);
        }
    });

    return data;
}


module.exports = IndexController;
```

Some advices could be very great ! By the way, I tried with xmlhttprequest too.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: **How** doesn't it work? Does it explode?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You need a callback.

Comment: Please read about how to write asynchronous programs. Hint: You'll *never* return the data in that function.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, if you would return data there, it would be empty. That is because of the asynchronous function handling of Node.js. (The function-call 'request(url,...)' is executed in the "same" time, as the returning of the variable 'data').

Look at the above mentioned request-function: it receives a callback function, containing all the logic that will be executed, once the function is done.

What you need for a start is the following; add a callback-function argument:

```
IndexController.prototype.execute = function (callbackFunc) {
    // do request as you intended
    request(url, function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        data = JSON.parse(body);
        callbackFunc(data); // then call callback-function with results
    }        
});
```

In the calling part of your logic, where IndexController is instantiated and 'IndexController.execute()' is called, you then call it with your callback-function as argument (ie. what should be done with the result):

```
var controller = IndexController(req, params);
controller.execute(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Hope that does for a start.